# User has been authenticated. Now what?

Tags: authentication, passwords, web-application

I'm trying to create a user authentication system for an application. I can't use a built in library for that such as ASP.NET Identity, but I can use any simple methods in .net.

Not wanting to rollout my own crypto, of course, I'm using PBKDF2 for authenticating the user's password. But this is where I'm stuck. I assume that now I need to create some temporary ID and have the client and server use that until some time expires without  client action. But I can't seem to find a source for this as most articles I've seen deal with ready made libraries.

So - am I correct? And if you have some source or more pointers, that would be welcome.

Comment: Would [sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) do the trick?

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. But from a first look, it seems that it relies on the client being a browser with cookies etc. being taken care of automatically. As I said, I'm talking about an application.

Comment: Use the same approach. Generate some random identifier you hand to the client, and store this and any information identifying the session on the server. The client can subsequently use this random identifier to authenticate communications.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but it seems like you need something that combines ideas from user/pass auth + api keys, but you want a temporary api key that is issued after login. This is starting to sound a lot like a session cookie ...

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks. I thought as much, but wanted some confirmation (which I failed to find by searching).

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Thanks. See my previous comment (to vidarlo).